# is a sentry QWidget a good idea (to prevent memory leaks when creating and populating a layout)?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, raii

This code snippet taken from http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qhboxlayout.html#details is, barring some magic I'm not aware of, full of potential memory leaks.

Edit: thanks to Nikos C. for pointing out that exception safety is odd in Qt as seen here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/exceptionsafety.html Therefore to keep the main intent of my question valid I updated the example code:

```
 QWidget *window = new QWidget;
 QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
 QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
 QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
 QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
 QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");

 QMyWidgetThatCanThrow *myWidget = new QMyWidgetThatCanThrow("");

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button1);
 layout->addWidget(button2);
 layout->addWidget(button3);
 layout->addWidget(button4);
 layout->addWidget(button5);
 layout->addWidget(myWidget);

 window->setLayout(layout);
 window->show();
```

Only at the very end are the widgets reparanted to the window so any exception before the last two lines will leak everything (assuming in real code the window has a parent).

In similar non Qt code I would use a sentry object to deal with this kind of thing. Is there a best practice way of using a sentry here which other people will understand when looking at my code?

Edit:
would this be an acceptable design pattern?

```
void PopulateWindow(QWidget *window)
{
     QWidget sentry;    //serves as the intial parent ensuring that all
                        //widgets are either reparented or deleted
     QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One",&sentry);
     QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two",&sentry);
     QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three",&sentry);
     QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four",&sentry);
     QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five",&sentry);

     QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(&sentry);
     layout->addWidget(button1);
     layout->addWidget(button2);
     layout->addWidget(button3);
     layout->addWidget(button4);
     layout->addWidget(button5);

     window->setLayout(layout);
}    //sentry goes out of scope and deletes anything that was not reparented
```

using it:

```
 QWidget *window = new QWidget;
 PopulateWindow(window);
 window->show();
```

Comment: Well if something goes wrong and there is an exception the program crash and the process is destroyed. No leaks.

Comment: What about if I don't want to let the program crash? seems like that should be considered too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what could go wrong? what is the issue you want to avoid? 
if you create widgets and there is anything which force you to abort, do like you do in regular C/C++

```
if(huhOh!!){
   delete button1;
   delete button2;
   ....
   return false
}
```

Edit:

Nothing prevents you from doing

```
void PopulateWindow(QWidget *window){

 QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One",window);
 QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two",window);
 QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three",window);
 QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four",window);
 QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five",window);

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(window);
 layout->addWidget(button1);
 layout->addWidget(button2);
 layout->addWidget(button3);
 layout->addWidget(button4);
 layout->addWidget(button5);

 //layout already set
 //window->setLayout(layout);
}
```

In this case you will just delete `window`

Comment: I'm talking about exceptions thrown. Lets say after creating two buttons I'm out of memory, where should I put your if? I would rather deal with it RAII style.

Comment: if the application is out of memory when you create your UI, I doubt you want it to keep running. Even if you do, what are you going to do next? Be detailed on this point

Comment: if I am creating this window as a floating window showing an editable image (for the sake of argument) and the user has opened 500 floating windows I will close any that have not been changed freeing up memory and tell the user he's stupid for opening 500 floating windows.

Comment: why not use try catch?? The issue with your sentry is that it is unusual and if anyone else is sharing the code, they will be tempted to change it to the version 1.

Comment: thats exactly what I was afraid of and why I asked the question. "Modern C++" (as decribed at length by most speakers at the last two C++ and beyond events) encourages using RAII and exceptions and sentry Objects. Most people I have worked with lately would also do it the "modern" way. However as you note Qt Programmers seem to like to do things differently, for better or for worse. I could use try catch but that would trigger a whole bunch of "thats not RAII, thats ugly" comments at code review.

Comment: If you want to satisfy someone in particular (superior, team) use their idioms. If they are all RAII over you, use your sentry they will be happy.

Comment: If I could defend it with "but this is best practice with Qt" I could use something else but as far as I have seen there is no real "best practice" out there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20574/discussion-between-porkybrain-and-umnyobe)